# In Illustrator, elements with SVG filters appear rasterized

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm trying to use SVG filters for the first time and I can't understand why they seem to be rendering so badly.

For reasons that I don't understand, when I apply any SVG filter, the element I've applied it to appears rasterized, making it impossible to work with the document any more. When I export this to SVG and open the SVG in a browser, it looks fine (smooth), but in Illustrator itself it looks awful.

As an example, I've created a new document, drawn a rectangle, rotated it 30%, duplicated it, and applied an SVG filter to one rectangle but not the other. The images below are a screenshot of this simple Illustrator document. The first rectangle doesn't have an SVG filter applied; the second rectangle is exactly the same rectangle with the AI_Shadow_2 SVG filter applied. I've zoomed in to 200% to show the issue I'm having more clearly:

[image: Rectangles with and without SVG filter applied]

But even at 100% it still looks really bad:

[image]

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong as I can't believe it's supposed to render like this?

Adobe Illustrator 24.1.3
Windows 10

Comment: SVG filters are raster filters -- "I've zoomed in to 200%" -- if you zoom in on a raster element, it's *going* to look pixelated. There's *no such thing* as a "vector blur" such as the blur applied to canned drop shadows.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was worried that people might focus on the fact that I've zoomed in to 200%, but I've only done that to illustrate the point more clearly - even at 100% it looks awful. I've updated the question with a screenshot at 100%.

I guess a better way to phrase the question might be, why does it look so bad in Illustrator, but it looks fine (and scales up infinitely) when you export it as SVG and open it in a browser?

Comment: I don't use the SVG filters.. but.. I get the *same* results you are getting... my guess is whether or not it's *supposed* to render that way.. it does due to the angle. I'd also guess that your original stroke is less than 1pt in weight and it's being bumped up to 1px minimum.

Comment: It's good to know it's not just me! It still seems weird to me and it makes me question how other people work with this. Once I've applied an SVG filter I basically can't work with the document any more because it looks so terrible. So I guess I'll just have to toggle visibility off then remember to toggle it back on every time I need to export to SVG.

Comment: If you *really* want it to be horrible, turn on Pixel Preview `:)`

Comment: You can adjust your document raster effects higher also you need to make the bounding box expansion higher. But given that svg effects dont even work in browsers half of the time most people in fact dont uses them. Its one of those things. I mean we would have been way better of with shader support ala opengl

Comment: Actually @joojaa DRES doesn't seem to factor into this.. I tried. [300PPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmMUh.png) vs [900PPI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y9Ck.png) I mean there's a *minor* shift, but nothing significant. I suppose of your'e working at 72 and bump it that may make a world of difference.

Comment: @Scott it does for me. But then i didnt test on illustrator CC or CS6 which you most likely run.anyway its possible i have altered the defaulr filter to behave less badly